# how to show value of y-axis value using manipulate to select x-axis value

Tags: manipulate

How to add a slider for the x-axis that shows the value of the y-axis based on the position of the slider.

Basically providing the result of the probably given a specific lot percent defective, lpd value.

I can calculate the value and when I use Column the calculation doesn't respond to changes in the plot's manipulated changes. If I put the calculation within the manipulate plot line - it shows and formatting is pretty hard to read.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[N[Probability[x<=c, x \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[SampleSize *lpd]]], {lpd,0,.1},
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Filling -> Axis],
 {SampleSize, 50, 1000, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {c, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
f[c_, lpd_, SampleSize_] := Probability[x <= c, Distributed[x , 
                                                      PoissonDistribution[SampleSize*lpd]]]; 
Manipulate[Show[
   Plot[f[c, lpd, SampleSize], {lpd, 0, .1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
        Filling -> Axis, Epilog -> Inset[Framed[Style[{point, f[c, point, SampleSize]}, 20], 
                                        Background -> LightYellow], Automatic, Automatic]], 
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{point, f[c, point, SampleSize]}]}]],

 {SampleSize, 50, 1000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {c, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {point, N@10^-8, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great - Show, and Epilog are new to me.

What is the N@10^-8 term for? to avoid zero?

thanks,

Fred

Comment: @FredSchenkelberg Yep, just to avoid the zero